# Render column depending on row rendering

Tags: jsf, tablecolumn, conditional-rendering

I have a dataTable like this one:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{myList}" var="myVariable" >
  <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header"/>
    <h:graphicImage style="display:block; margin:0px auto" value="imageURL" rendered="#{condition}"/>
  </h:column>
  <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
      Attribute1
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText style="display:block; text-align:center" value="#{myVariable.attribute1}" />
  </h:column>
  <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
      Attribute2
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText style="display:block; text-align:center" value="#{myVariable.attribute2}" />
  </h:column>
  <h:column>
    <f:facet name="header">
      Attribute3
    </f:facet>
    <h:outputText style="display:block; text-align:center" value="#{myVariable.attribute3}" />
  </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

As you can see, I have multiple columns displaying all the attributes of a variable, and an image which is shown in a column if a condition is satisfied.

[image: Alert image]

However, not fulfilling that condition give us a table with an empty column which I would like to not being shown.

[image: Empty column]

Is there any way to hide that column when no image is shown in all the rows?

Comment: Are you using the [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) plugin?

Comment: @Roshana: Nope. OP is using JSF.

Comment: @Carlos: please don't use [java] tag when asking JSF questions. Java SE users are not per definitinon capable of understanding and answering JSF questions. Just stick to [jsf] as main tag.

Comment: in your bean you could run through the data and determine whether the image would be shown or not.  store this in a boolean (e.g. imageShown).  and then  `<h:column rendered="#{myBean.imageShown}">`

Comment: @MitchBroadhead I thought about it but that's another loop through all the data... If there are 10 rows that's not a problem, but what if you have 1M rows...

Comment: you could do it as a query, or as you construct the data.